# subscribing to Yahoo search feed with google reader?

Tags: yahoo, google-reader, yahoo-search

Is it possible to subscribe to Yahoo search results with google reader through reader api?

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo search results can be returned in RSS format, which can then be passed to the Google Reader API for subscription.

The Yahoo RSS feed URL format is (for search term 'nascar'):

`http://api.search.yahoo.com/WebSearchService/rss/webSearch.xml?appid=yahoosearchwebrss&query=nascar`

Unfortunately it looks like these feeds are not returning results at the moment. It's possible that they've been discontinued.

As an alternative, you can use the Bing search RSS feeds which have the format:

`http://www.bing.com/search?format=rss&q=nascar`

Bing search results power Yahoo search, so you'll get the same (or close to the same) results either way.